# SQL Regexp and PL/SQL Update Statement

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, plsql, sql-update

I am currently facing the following problem:

In my database I have different description which need to be adjusted. Thereby, these strings can have different forms:

```
Part 1 (ehem. 123) - Part 2 - [Part 3]
Part 1 (ehem. 123) - [Part 3]
Part1-Part1 (ehem 123)
```

--> Part 1 may contain a `-` in the word, e.g. E-Banking

My goal is to write a PL/SQL update statement ensuring that everything on the right side is being trimmed up to (ehem. 123). So, `(ehem. 123)` should be still displayed, the rest on the right trimmed. Or, I want to trim everything on the right side with the first occurrence of a whitespace followed by the character `'-'` --> `' -'`

My first approach was the following and it works perfectly fine for the second form (i.e. `Part 1 (ehem. 123) - [Part 3]`)

```
substr(regexp_substr(oct.descn, '.*\-'),1,length(regexp_substr(oct.descn, '.*\-'))-2)
```

However, once I face form 1 or 3 (with a `'-'` in the middle of string) `"part 1"`, it does not work anymore.

So, here are the questions:

1. How can I ensure, that in any case I will get only this part of the string with a SQL reg expression?
   --> `Part 1 (ehem. 123)`
2. How do I need to write my PL/SQL statement so that all relevant records are being updated (id,descn). I started something with a for loop, looping over all relevant descn and updating these.

Answer (score 0):

(1) Use this regexp:

```
create table yytest(id number, descn varchar2(100));

insert into yytest values(1,'Part 1 (ehem. 123) - Part 2 - [Part 3]');
insert into yytest values(1,'Part 1 (ehem. 123) - [Part 3]');
insert into yytest values(1,'Part1-Part1 (ehem 123)');

select regexp_replace(descn, '\s-.*') from yytest;
```

This will result in

```
Part 1 (ehem. 123)
Part 1 (ehem. 123)
Part1-Part1 (ehem 123)
```

Basically, in the regexp_replace, it replaces whitespace `\s` fowllowed by `-` followed by anything `.*` with nothing (no third argument).

(2) For the update, simply update all rows:

```
update yytest set descn=regexp_replace(descn, '\s-.*');
```

If you want to limit the number of updates, you might want to add:

```
where descn != regexp_replace(descn, '\s-.*')
```

So only the rows that need change will be updated;